# Iterate over padded area in 2D array in python

Tags: python, loops, padding

Assume I have a 2D array in Python and I add some padding. How can I iterate over the new padded area **only**?

For example

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Becomes

```
x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x
x x 1 2 3 x x
x x 4 5 6 x x
x x 7 8 9 x x
x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x
```

How can I loop over only the x's?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but if you are using numpy, you can use masks:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(np.arange(1,10)).reshape(3,3)

# mask full of True's
mask = np.ones((7,7),dtype=bool)
# setting the interior of the mask as False
mask[2:-2,2:-2] = False
# using zero padding as example
pad_arr = np.zeros((7,7))
pad_arr[2:-2,2:-2] = arr

print(pad_arr)

# loop for elements of the padding, where mask == True
for value in pad_arr[mask]:
    print(value)
```

Returns:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 4. 5. 6. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 7. 8. 9. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

and `0.0` 40 times (the padded values)